# Archer - How to implement Automatic Findings

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I would like to know in what circumstances the Automatic Findings can be set. Is it related to a workflow? If not, how can you trigger an Automatic Finding with a simple example that I can carry out as a test?
Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Giovanni

Answer (score 0):

Giovanni, in the questionnaire (Manage Questionnaires) on the Properties tab, then the Campaigns tab you would either configure the Automated and/or Manual Campaigns.  Check the online help for more information on how to configure each of these sections.